# React typescript - object is possibly undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, undefined, setstate

I am trying to build a dropdown component in typescript and have run into an error.

I create the type and the data.

```
type DropdownType = {
  id: number;
  label: string;
};
const data: DropdownType[] = [
  { id: 0, label: "Istanbul, TR (AHL)" },
  { id: 1, label: "Paris, FR (CDG)" },
];
```

the set the initial data

```
  const [items, setItem] = useState<DropdownType[]>(data);
```

However typescript tells me it is possibly undefined

```
 {selectedItem
          ? items.find((item: DropdownType) => item.id === selectedItem).label
          : "Select your destination"}
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

https://codesandbox.io/s/morning-leftpad-5ohhv?file=/src/Dropdown.tsx:1609-1741

Answer (score 4):

It is because of the fact that `.find` function returns undefined if the condition is never met. So:

```
items.find((item: DropdownType) => item.id === selectedItem)
```

can return undefined. You can use `conditional chaining`:

```
items.find((item: DropdownType) => item.id === selectedItem)?.label
```

Comment: nice one I actually tried it on the othe end -  items?.find((item: DropdownType) => item.id === selectedItem).label

Comment: Apart from that, why do you use `==` and not `===`? I strongly suggest using triple equals :)